# Serilog console outputs doesn't show up during Integration Testing with WebApplicationFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, console, integration-testing, serilog

The log entry shows up fine in the test console when I call `Log.Information("Test")` from my integration test file. If I call the same static function from within the controller being tested with a **WebApplicationFactory**, nothing will show up in the test console.

Oddly enough, `Console.WriteLine("Test")` also doesn't show up in the test console when called from a controller created with a **WebApplicationFactory**

Is there a way to display in the test console log entries dispatched from controllers being tested using a **WebApplicationFactory**? Or simply a way to redirect console output from the created WebHost to the test output?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74574304/1057436

In ASP 6 you can set `PreserveExecutionContext` like this:

```
public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
    _factory.Server.PreserveExecutionContext = true;
}
```

Code from this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory